# Can gravity be the high-energy regularizer for QFTs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, regularization

In order for QFTs to be mathematically well-defined some sort of regularization scheme needs to be introduced, which typically looks like a discrete cutoff of all modes outside of some shell with energy $\Lambda$ (or something smoother as in Polchinski's functional renormalization group).

Meanwhile, gravitation naturally gives a maximum energy density on the order of the Planck mass, due to the irrevocable formation of black holes at these energies. My question is: were one to be able to consistently couple gravity to fluctuating quantum fields (a big ask, to be sure!), would this intrinsic physical energy cutoff provide a natural regularization for quantum field theories? Or, is there some obstacle to interpreting gravity itself as the regularizer.

Comment: That is the belief, yes.

Comment: [On the other hand](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3555), gravity can't have a QFT as we currently understand the concept, so if gravity really did specify the regularization of other interactions the kind of "QFT" in which it did so would be very unfamiliar.